# Preserving an HTML/non-HTML version of a WMD textarea in Django?

Tags: django, wmd

I setup the default `wmd.js` to my admin textareas for my Bug models. Now it gets saved as HTML and when I go to edit the entry in the admin, I see the literal HTML:

```
<p>foo</p>
```

What strategy could I use so it only renders this `<p>foo</p>` in the views/HTML instead of the edit view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to make the Markdown save as "Markdown" type, and use the `markdown` Django module to keep a second column of my textarea (the pure one).

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the output as safe so it doesn't get autoescaped. See the [autoescaping docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#id2).